# How to determine the user's country code in Azure AD

Tags: timezone, azure-active-directory, botframework

I'm trying to determine the user's time zone in the BOT that I created. This Bot can be user worldwide and the only way for me to determine the user's timezone is to determine his country (because the channel that i user is skype and there isn't any information about the user's TZ unlike other channel's).

So is there a way to determine the client's country code in azure AD ?

Comment: You are talking about "Skype" and "Azure AD"... What is the link here? Skype users are not necessary users registered in an Azure AD. Or did you mean Skype for Business?

Comment: Excuse me. Yes i meant skype for business channel.

Comment: Many countries have more than one time zone.  Determining the country isn't enough to determine a time zone.

Comment: I totally understand that country isn't a good reference to determine the timezone but i'm out of options here and i don't see any other choice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are having your users login to your bot with AAD, you could use the same token to access the user's profile via the Microsoft Graph API. The profile will give the users office location which you could then map to for a possible location. It won't account for a user who might be traveling but, it's an option.

You can read the Microsoft Graph [docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) to learn more and experiment using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#).

As I don't know which SDK or version you are using, if you visit the [BotBuilder repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder) you can find links to [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-samples) on how to build a bot that uses OAuth and makes calls to Microsoft Graph.